# I want to split one huge file according to the splitsize using multithread in java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, split

I have a huge .txt file of 1gb which i want to split using the formula total_input_size/split_size. This would give the number of splits to be done with the file.I want to generate threads which should be equal to the number of splits so that each thread should carry the task of splitting and writing the .txt in new file in a parallel manner and store it in a folder.At the same time while writing into file it should append in the file that it is file 1, file 2 and so on.

Can anyone tell me how should I do in Java 7 and 8.And what is the best way to give more performance. If there is any other way what could it be.

Comment: Consider inserting some code that you have tried here.  Have you worked on this at all or want someone to write the whole thing for you?

Comment: I think single threaded split will perform better than multithread. You also mention recombining. The extra effort of synchronizing all the threads to recombine the file will definitely cost you. Unless you first read the file into some buffer of sorts, if each thread reads the file, that is another bottleneck. Don't bring a gun to a knife fight bro, keep it simple.

Comment: Start doing it in a sequential way. I doubt you will gain performance by doing it with multiple threads. BTW, 1GB is nowhere near huge nowadays. Once you have implemented a sequential solution you should be able to extract a method to write a portion of the file, and invoke this method concurrently rather than sequentially.

Comment: I would use fileInsputstream.read and utilize the offset capability. Each thread would need to create its own instance of fileinputstream, though. I agree with the others, however, that a sequential approach for 1GB is more than adequate.

Comment: I dont want to combine the whole splitted file. Infact I would random select some file and then combine to give the result.